# Automatically decrease the size of a CSS property

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have this image with width="192" and height="109":

```
<a href="https://www.blogger.com/u/1/blogger.g?blogID=4402911157743442948#"><img alt="" class="thumbnail" height="109" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-E5ftfbCCgkw/XjnLpO347cI/AAAAAAAAAE8/85xzQpWk1Q8-8A8le4Zj4zPlzs4xCRIcQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/1974%2B-%2BKamen%2BRider%2BAmazon%2BEpis%25C3%25B3dios.jpg" width="192"></a>
```

and I have this `.playWrapper` that puts a play button over the image. The thing is, when I'm on the phone or device that changes the photo size, the `.playWrapper` width stays the same, because the only way I see to do this is setting it manually. I have tried put **width: auto;** but it does not work. How do I do that in order to the `.playWrapper` width follows the image width?

Here is the playWrapper CSS code:

```
.overlay .playWrapper{opacity:0;position:absolute;z-index:1;top:0;width:192px;height:109px;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6) url("http://wptf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/play-button.png") no-repeat scroll center center/50px 50px}
```

Comment: So you want the image to expand, but the play button to stay the same size?

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the width and height of both the image, and the playWrapper with percentages instead of pixels. For example: instead of `width:192px;` you could have something like `width=10%;` in the css. If you the size of a screen and a width and height of the image that looks good, you could calculate the percentages that would make the image look the same on that screen size. Make sure to put this on both the image and playWrapper, so they are the same size. Because of the percentages, they will change size with screen size. Good luck and hopefully this works for you!

Comment: I'm going to try. I'll let you know if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For an absolutely positioned element which is relative to another element (i.e. it's parent element) which can change size, it's often better not to use `height` and `width` values, but instead use `top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;`

If the element shouldn't fill/cover it's parent completely, you can also change these vaues from 0 to some px value, or for example use this to create an element than spans the whole (variable) width, but only is 30px high at the bottom of the paren:

```
.your_overlay_element {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome! If my answer solved your question, please mark it as accepted or/and give it an upvote.